# Chromium will not start in Guest Session on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: chromium

In Guest Session ,when i try to launch chromium-browser via GUI,the icon pops up on the left and disappears.so i tried
starting chromium-browser from terminal, I got:

> /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser: error while loading shared libraries: libffmpeg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

so i logged in with admin account and reinstalled it via GUI but still it didn't change a thing.I am facing this problem only while using the Guest Session and i am running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

Anybody else experiencing similar issues lately?

Looking forward to hearing from you, 
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same issue. I wrote my findings so far here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1718885

Even though I don't have a good solution to this problem, if you are blocked by this like I am, I have a workaround to make chromium work right now:

`sudo cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/./libffmpeg.so /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

Answer (score 0):

See this bug report, which is likely the same issue:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1718885